# get name of css ID in a form in twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I'm building a form in my sf2 project,so to provide a input I do in twig :

```
{{ form_widget(form.price)  }}
```

the output is:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" required="required" 
       name="mybundle_appbundle_producttype[price]"
         id="mybundle_appbundle_producttype_price">
```

My question is: How to get the name or content of "id" only `mybundle_appbundle_producttype_price` in twig?

Because for every field I'll use the CSS id in Javascript code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get all possible params with `{{ dump(form.price) }}`. If I remember correctly id accessable via `{{ form.price.vars.id }}`